# 'chromedriver.exe' executable may have wrong permissions error for android

Tags: python, android, kivy, selenium-chromedriver, buildozer

I try to run the following code by an application build by kivy buildozer :

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chrome_options.add_argument('headless')

chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': 'en,en_UK'})

chrome_options.add_experimental_option('androidPackage', 'com.android.chrome')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/storage/emulated/0/chromedriver.exe',options=chrome_options)
```

I get the following error from the adb logcat:
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message:

> 'chromedriver.exe' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see
> https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home 07-25 17:05:33.791 27719 27763
> I python  : 07-25 17:05:33.791 27719 27763 I python  : Python for
> android ended.

I use chrome driver version 103.0.5060.134 and chromebrowser version 103.0.5060.129 and latest selenium version and android 12.

I tried changing the permission of the chromedriver.exe using:
adb shell su -c "chmod 777 "
but still not working.

Comment: `.exe` files are Windows executable and won't run on Android. Testing of Chrome browser is usually run from a PC not on Android device.

Comment: Thank you but do you know how to run it from android ?